# AD mapping error with VMware

Tags: sql-server, vmware-workstation

I'm trying to setup a VMware Data Center with Win Server 2008 R2 and SQL 2012.
I have a VM that hosts DHCP and DNS services and created an account called "SQLAdmin" that is a local admin to a SQL VM as well.

However, when I try to install SQL 2012 on the SQL VM, I get error “S-1-5-XX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-1104: No mapping between account names and security IDs was done.”

I couldn't find a way to get around so I used default settings. then later on, I cannot access the database on Management Studio.

I so far have refreshed ipconfig and turned off all Windows Firewall(s). I erased the AD account to start from scratch as well with no luck.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Is the DHCP/DNS VM also hosting AD?  Is the SQL VM using the AD DNS as it's only DNS server?

Comment: Correct, DHCP/DNS VM does AD as well. That's the usual trend, right? I wasn't aware there were specific steps to have SQL VM get AD off of DHCP/DNS VM.

Comment: In case someone struggles with similar issue, please refer to this. As someone from another forum suggested http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/bradleyschacht/2012/09/04/error-no-mapping-between-account-names-and-security-ids-was-done/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered a similar problem when setting up vCenter.

When installation gets out of order, things get messy and it's best to start from scratch.

I do this whenever VMware installation fails:
(1) Reinstall Windows Server
(2) Install any outstanding Service Pack
(3) SQL Server Enterprise
(4) vCenter server

If you skip any steps, you'll run into mapping error.